# Cookies not loading in discord selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, cookies

I have such a situation, I log into the discord and then save the cookies with this code

`pickle.dump (driver.get_cookies (), open (r "cookies_discord.pkl", "wb"))`

after which I switch to a new browser and try to load cookies on the https://discord.com/ discord page on it and save cookies

but after the cookies are loaded, the page is still not logged in to me

with twitter all the same works fine

here is the code for loading cookies

`for cookie_discord in pickle.load (open (r "cookies_discord.pkl", "rb")):`
`driver.add_cookie (cookie_discord)`

Comment: can you post any error that you get?

Answer (score 3):

The browser version of Discord doesn't just use cookies for login.

However, you can get access to your account using your **user token**, which is a pretty long string that looks something like this:

```
"A1b2C3d4E5f6.G7H8.i9J0A1b2C3d4E5f6"
```

With this string, you have absolute access to the account, and it is valid until you change your password. (No password, authenticator, or 2FA required)

You can get your **user token** by running this JavaScript in your browser console:

```js
(webpackChunkdiscord_app.push([[''],{},e=>{m=[];for(let c in e.c)m.push(e.c[c])}]),m).find(m=>m?.exports?.default?.getToken!==void 0).exports.default.getToken()
```

Once you have your **user token**, you can login to your account using this JavaScript (change the "PASTE_YOUR_TOKEN_HERE" with your own token):

```js
(function() {window.t = 
"PASTE_YOUR_TOKEN_HERE"
;window.localStorage = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement `iframe`).contentWindow.localStorage;window.setInterval(() => window.localStorage.token = `"${window.t}"`); window.location.reload();})();
```

I advise you run this JavaScript every time you run your bot, instead of trying to achieve it using cookies.

You can run JS scripts in Python Selenium using this function:

```py
driver.execute_script("JavaScript code here")
```

Answer (score 0):

Discord doesn't just use cookies for login.
Some userdata is set in the localstorage in the browser.

You'll need to copy this too in order for discord to log you in.
[image: discord data]